# How to make a line plot from a pandas dataframe with a long or wide format

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

*(This is a self-answered post to help others shorten their answers to plotly questions by not having to explain how plotly best handles data of long and wide format)*

---

I'd like to build a plotly figure based on a pandas dataframe in as few lines as possible. I know you can do that using plotly.express, but this fails for what I would call a standard pandas dataframe; an index describing row order, and column names describing the names of a value in a dataframe:

#### Sample dataframe:

```
    a           b           c
0   100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
1   98.493705   99.421400   101.651437
2   96.067026   98.992487   102.917373
3   95.200286   98.313601   102.822664
4   96.691675   97.674699   102.378682
```

#### An attempt:

```
fig=px.line(x=df.index, y = df.columns)
```

This raises an error:

> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 3, whereas the length of previous arguments ['x'] is 100`

Comment: great Q/A pair.  I wonder if df.T might be useful?

Comment: @anon01 Thanks! `df.T` is *extremely* useful. But what did you have in mind in particular?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here you've tried to use a pandas dataframe of a wide format as a source for `px.line`.
And `plotly.express` is designed to be used with dataframes of a [long format](https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/), often referred to as [tidy data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) (and *please* take a look at that. No one explains it better that Wickham). Many, particularly those injured by years of battling with Excel, often find it easier to organize data in a wide format. So what's the difference?

#### Wide format:

- data is presented with each different data variable in a separate column
- each column has only one data type
- missing values are often represented by `np.nan`
- works best with [plotly.graphobjects](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/plotly.graph_objects.html) (`go`)
- lines are often added to a figure using `fid.add_traces()`
- colors are normally assigned to each trace

**Example:**

```
            a          b           c
0   -1.085631    0.997345   0.282978
1   -2.591925    0.418745   1.934415
2   -5.018605   -0.010167   3.200351
3   -5.885345   -0.689054   3.105642
4   -4.393955   -1.327956   2.661660
5   -4.828307    0.877975   4.848446
6   -3.824253    1.264161   5.585815
7   -2.333521    0.328327   6.761644
8   -3.587401   -0.309424   7.668749
9   -5.016082   -0.449493   6.806994
```

#### Long format:

- data is presented with one column containing all the values and another column listing the context of the value
- missing values are simply not included in the dataset.
- works best with [plotly.express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) (`px`)
- colors are set by a default color cycle and are assigned to each unique variable

**Example:**

```
    id  variable    value
0   0   a        -1.085631
1   1   a        -2.591925
2   2   a        -5.018605
3   3   a        -5.885345
4   4   a        -4.393955
... ... ... ...
295 95  c        -4.259035
296 96  c        -5.333802
297 97  c        -6.211415
298 98  c        -4.335615
299 99  c        -3.515854
```

#### How to go [from wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)?

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', value_vars=df.columns[:-1])
```

#### The two snippets below will produce the very same plot:

[image]

#### How to use px to plot long data?

```
fig = px.line(df, x='id', y='value', color='variable')
```

#### How to use go to plot wide data?

```
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['id'], y = df['a'], mode = 'lines', line=dict(color=colors[0])))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['id'], y = df['b'], mode = 'lines', line=dict(color=colors[1])))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['id'], y = df['c'], mode = 'lines', line=dict(color=colors[2])))
fig.show()
```

By the looks of it, `go` is more complicated and offers perhaps more flexibility? Well, yes. And no. You can easily build a figure using `px` and add any `go` object you'd like!

**Complete go snippet:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# dataframe of a wide format
np.random.seed(123)
X = np.random.randn(100,3)  
df=pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['a','b','c'])
df=df.cumsum()
df['id']=df.index

# plotly.graph_objects
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['id'], y = df['a'], mode = 'lines', line=dict(color=colors[0])))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['id'], y = df['b'], mode = 'lines', line=dict(color=colors[1])))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['id'], y = df['c'], mode = 'lines', line=dict(color=colors[2])))
fig.show()
```

**Complete px snippet:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import iplot

# dataframe of a wide format
np.random.seed(123)
X = np.random.randn(100,3)  
df=pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['a','b','c'])
df=df.cumsum()
df['id']=df.index

# dataframe of a long format
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', value_vars=df.columns[:-1])

# plotly express
fig = px.line(df, x='id', y='value', color='variable')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the Wickham article! Since this answer was written, [plotly express now does accept wide form data](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/) in some instances.

Comment: @mcat You're welcome! Wickhams contributions to R is what I miss the most about using R. An regarding this Q&A, it was something I'd had in mind for quite some time. And when I finally posted it, the new px functionalities were released the very next day...

Comment: I think that's a typo     "How to go from long to wide?",  `melt` should be "wide to long"

Comment: @miaoz2001 You're right! Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 5):

You can change the pandas plotting backend to use [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/):

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

Then, to get a fig all you need to write is:

```py
fig = df.plot()
```

[image: result of fig.show()]

*`fig.show()` displays the above image.*

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to add this as answer so it will be on evidence.
First of all thank you @vestland for this. It's a question that come over and over so it's good to have this addressed and it could be easier to flag duplicated question.

**Plotly Express now accepts wide-form and mixed-form data**
as you can check in this [post](https://medium.com/plotly/beyond-tidy-plotly-express-now-accepts-wide-form-and-mixed-form-data-bdc3e054f891).

Comment: Hah! I guess it's back to school for me then... The article is dated 26 may. Was it really released *today*? (no time to read right now. I'm on a boat...)

Comment: Plotly 4.8 was just released. I found on my twitter TL